# R Web Scraping?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am working on a web scraping assignment on the following website:

http://gomason.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball

I am asked to calculate the average score for the men’s team (Mason only) when they won a game and when they lost a game.

The score for each game is listed on the right side of each row in the format Mason’s score-Opponent’s score. For example, the first listed game has the score 67-65. By using the SelectorGadget tool, I determined the CSS selector needed to scrape this information, and then wrote the code that scrapes this information. This vector has 33 pieces of data in it. I used the separate() function to separate Mason's score from the Opponent's score.

I have tried a couple of things but it gives me the following error:

```
mens_bb <- read_html("http://gomason.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball", na = c("NA")) 

mens_scores <- mens_bb %>%
html_nodes("div.sidearm-schedule-game-result span:nth-child(3)") %>%
html_text()
as.numeric()
as.double()

mens_df <- data_frame(
  date = mens_dates, time = mens_times, opponent = mens_opponents, location = mens_locations, score = mens_scores, win_loss = mens_win_loss)

mens_df$score <- as.numeric(mens_df$score)       
mens_df$score <- as.double(mens_df$score)

NAs introduced by coercion

mens_df %>% separate(score, c("Mason’s score", "Opponent’s score"), sep = "\\-") 

mens_average <- mean(score, na = c("NA")) 

argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

It listed all the scores as NAs now and the variable score persist as a chr type. How could I resolve this?

This is how mens_df looks like before separating the score values:

```
Observations: 33
Variables: 6
$ date     <chr> "Nov 10 (Fri)", "Nov 12 (Sun)", "Nov 16 (Thu)", "No...
$ time     <chr> "7:00 p.m. ", "2:00 p.m. ", "7:00 p.m. ", "6:00 p.m...
$ opponent <chr> "Lafayette ", "Louisville", "Binghamton ", "CSUN", ...
$ location <chr> "Fairfax, Va.", "Louisville, Ky.", "Fairfax, Va. ",...
$ score    <chr> "67-65", "61-72", "69-57", "78-73", "64-77", "73-79...
$ win_loss <chr> "W", "L", "W", "W", "L", "L", "W", "L", "L", "W", "...
```

Comment: `mens_scores` is never put into anything after scraping, also, what is in `mens_df`? Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: I introduced the editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# read webpage/ extract only container with relevant info 
bb_mason <- read_html("http://gomason.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball")  %>% 
            xml_find_all(".//ul[@class = 'sidearm-schedule-games-container']")

# vector with xpath to extract required info
bb_xpath <- c(opponent = ".//span[@class = 'sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-name']/a",
       location = ".//div[@class = 'sidearm-schedule-game-location']/span[1]",
       result = ".//div[@class = 'sidearm-schedule-game-result text-italic']/span[2]",
       score = ".//div[@class = 'sidearm-schedule-game-result text-italic']/span[3]")

# sapply all xpath values, fetch information, and store in data frame tibble
bb_df <- tbl_df(
             sapply(bb_xpath, function(x) { 
                                    bb_mason %>% 
                                      xml_find_all(x) %>%
                                      xml_text(trim = T) }))

# separate scores, replace values in result column with more appropriate values,
# convert to numeric, and calculate average
bb_df %>% 
  separate("score", c("mason", "opp"), sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(mason = as.numeric(mason), 
         opp = as.numeric(opp),
         result = plyr::mapvalues(result, c("W,", "L,"), c("Won", "Lost"))) %>% 
  group_by(result) %>% 
  summarize(avg.score = mean(mason))
```

Final output:

```
#  A tibble: 2 x 2
#   result avg.score
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Lost        65.7
# 2 Won         78.4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was asking for and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `as.numeric()` too early, as the score still contains a dash ('-'). That is why you are getting `NA`'s.

You can do the following: (I have created a new dataframe containing only the scores).

```
library(rvest)
mens_bb <- read_html("http://gomason.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball", na = c("NA")) 

mens_scores <- mens_bb %>%
  html_nodes("div.sidearm-schedule-game-result span:nth-child(3)") %>%
  html_text()

library(tidyr)
mens_df1 <- data.frame(mens_scores)
mens_df1 <- mens_df %>% separate(mens_scores, c("Mason_score", "Opponent_score"), sep = "\\-")
mens_df1$Mason_score <- as.numeric(mens_df1$Mason_score)
mens_average <- mean(mens_df1$Mason_score)
#71.84848
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the separation before the conversion to `numeric`. For instance, the following will give you your desired result.

```
mens_df <- data.frame(mens_scores)
mens_df %>% separate(mens_scores, c("Mason’s score", "Opponent’s score"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% summarise_all(mean)

#   Mason’s score Opponent’s score
# 1         71.85            75.67
```